# Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at' and npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node.js and have run other programs before. I re-installed node from scratch, and tried starting the server:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 10.16.3 (x64) and npm.

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Adam>cd documents\alan

C:\Users\Adam\Documents\alan>node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'simple-ngram-markov'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
```

...

```
C:\Users\Adam\Documents\alan>npm install simple-ngram-markov
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
```

...

```
C:\Users\Adam\Documents\alan>npm install code-point-at
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at'
Require stack:
```

...

Am I doing something wrong?

Last I tried this:

```
C:\Users\Adam>cd Documents\alan

C:\Users\Adam\Documents\alan>npm install 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657 throw err; ^

Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16) at Object. (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no de_modules\wide-align\node_modules\string-width\index.js:3:19) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
```

---

The repo is here: https://github.com/alexbinary/alan

Answer (score 0):

Two things straight up:

1. Run `npm init -y` to initialise a `package.json` file to track your dependencies. Then when you run `npm i ${package}` the package you install will be added to your package.json. This allows you (and others) to install all dependencies with `npm i`.
2. Put your `require` statements at the top of the file, and assign them to constants, rather than requiring in-line. This makes your dependencies easier to read and reason about, and means that your program will fail fast if a dependency is missing, rather than when a statement is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: Even doing `npm init -y` there is a throw error for `Cannot find module 'code-point-at'`.

Comment: This is a problem with your npm installation. Apparently rebooting can sometimes fix it: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6631#issuecomment-313835247